# php redirect page echo submitted results

Tags: php, redirect, submit, echo, form-submit

I am looking to have submitted form data displayed on a redirect page as well as be emailed to the user as well as myself. I have gotten the Email portion to work, now i'm trying to figure out the best way redirect to a separate page and display the submitted content.

```
       <?php 

    $emailSubject = 'MFPT Submission';
    $webMaster = 'todd@treble-one.com';

    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $FirstName = $_REQUEST['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $_REQUEST['LastName'];
    $organization = $_REQUEST['organization'];
    $AddressLine1 = $_REQUEST['AddressLine1'];
    $AddressLine2 = $_REQUEST['AddressLine2'];
    $City = $_REQUEST['City'];
    $StateProvince = $_REQUEST['StateProvince'];
    $Country = $_REQUEST['Country'];
    $ZipPostalCode = $_REQUEST['ZipPostalCode'];
    $Telephone = $_REQUEST['Telephone'];
    $Title = $_REQUEST['Title'];
    $WrittenPaper = $_REQUEST['WrittenPaper'];
    $Suggested_Conference_Session = $_REQUEST['Suggested_Conference_Session'];
    $Suggested_Conference_Track_Other = $_REQUEST['Suggested_Conference_Track_Other'];
    $CoAuthor = $_REQUEST['CoAuthor'];
    $Abstract = $_REQUEST['Abstract'];

    $body = <<<EOD

Email: $Email 
FirstName: $FirstName 
LastName: $LastName 
organization: $organization 
AddressLine1: $AddressLine1
AddressLine2: $AddressLine2
City: $City
StateProvince: $StateProvince
Country: $Country
ZipPostalCode: $ZipPostalCode
Telephone: $Telephone
Title: $Title
WrittenPaper: $WrittenPaper
Suggested_Conference_Session: $Suggested_Conference_Session 
Suggested_Conference_Track_Other: $Suggested_Conference_Track_Other
CoAuthor: $CoAuthor
Abstract: $Abstract
Comments: $Comments 
EOD;

 $host = "mail.treble-one.com";
 $username = "todd@treble-one.com";
 $password = "*******";

$headers = 'From: Your name <mfpt@mfpt.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content=type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: $Email\r\n";


$success = mail ($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,$headers);



echo $body;

?>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `header('Location: ...')`?

Comment: Is that teh "best way" @MarcB? ;-)

Comment: well, "best way" is an opinion, and opinions are off-topic, so...

Comment: Aren't you already getting the results you want displayed? What is the point of redirecting?

Comment: Right, I would like to redirect to have the content appear in my site template oppose to echoing to a white screen as it does now. maybe there is an easier way then redirecting?

Comment: Include the template around the `echo $body`... just like you would have to do if you redirected to a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming here that the code you posted here is in fact the form post action, something like  `send.php`.

You've handled the email body and you've already got the emails working. In fact, the easiest way to "display" the submitted content is by adding:

```
echo $body;
```

I think that's not what you're looking for, you want to redirect. I think you are not aware that you can display the information in this file as well, it doesn't need to be a separate file just to handle the post form. By adding HTML to this file you can show them the submitted info, [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

If you really need a redirect, you will have to either [save the data in a session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp), or redirect with the [data saved in the GET parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), although I would call neither good practice.

One last tip: [validate your submitted form](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp) before doing anything with it. An invalid email address will highly likely crash your PHP script.